# Python - Write to specific part of file, not by line - Regex

Tags: python, regex, file, text, io

What I would like to do is write in a value into a specific part of a file. This part can be anywhere in the file, but will appear only once, therefore I don't believe adding a line will solve it.

What I have is essentially a text file with:

```
TitleThing (
Some info = 22 

(More info = 22.2)
Tags = [] 
)
```

What I would like to do is add a string to the file right inside of the [] after Tags =.

Would looks like:

```
TitleThing (
Some info = 22 
Otherthing -- "56.foo"
(More info = 22.2)

Tags = ["newtag"] 
)
```

The other issue is that there may be existing tags:

```
TitleThing (
Some info = 22 

(More info = 22.2)
Tags = ["oldtag, othertag"] 
)
```

In this situation I would like to add my "newtag" to the exiting list so that it appears first.

I have start with:

```
tagRegex = re.compile(r'Tags = [(.*)]')
```

But I'm not sure how to proceed.

Would love some help!

Thanks.

Comment: You don't need a regex but you will need to write to a temporary file

Comment: thanks for the reply! Could you explain?

Comment: You are looking for `Tags =...`?

Comment: Text files are just a string of bytes going from the first character through to the last.  We see separators as newlines, but each is just one character in the file.  You can only add to the end of the file (append).  If you write to somewhere else you will just overwrite existing text on the next line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to write to a temporary file then overwrite the original.

```
from tempfile import NamedTemporaryFile
from shutil import move


def add_new(new):
    with open("check.txt") as f, NamedTemporaryFile("w",delete=False) as tmp:
        for line in f:
            if line.startswith("Tags ="):
                repl = ", {}]".format(new) if "[]" not in line else "{}]".format(new)
                tmp.write(line.replace("]", repl))
                tmp.writelines(f)
                break
            tmp.write(line)
    move(tmp.name, "check.txt")
```

Then just pass in the new value:

```
In [3]: cat check.txt
TitleThing (
Some info = 22 

(More info = 22.2)
Tags = []
)
In [4]: add_new("newvalue")

In [5]: cat check.txt
TitleThing (
Some info = 22 

(More info = 22.2)
Tags = [newvalue]
)
In [6]: add_new("newvalue2")

In [7]: cat check.txt
TitleThing (
Some info = 22 

(More info = 22.2)
Tags = [newvalue, newvalue2]
)
```

If you wanted the new value at the start, you need to just change the logic slightly:

```
   repl = "[{}, ".format(new) if "[]" not in line else "[{}".format(new)
   tmp.write(line.replace("[", repl))
```

Based on your comment change the if to:

```
if  '"Tags": [' in line:
```

Comment: This looks right but when I run it, the file is not written to. Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: @flec8,. it is definitely right based on what you have provided. Are you sure you are using the correct string to match to and have no leading whitespace?

Comment: ah you're right! what I have is 

TitleThing (
Some info = 22 

(More info = 22.2)
"Tags" : [],
)

Comment: lol, then just use that in place of what is in the question, is that one line?

Answer (score 0):

A dirty idea: you could read the line with `Tags = ...`, evaluate it, edit the list, then rewrite it:

```
exec('Tags = ["newtag"]')
Tags.append("othertag")
f.write('Tags = {}'.format(Tags))
```

where `f` is a new file where you write the edited version (or use a temp file as in the other answer).

(Of course it is always dangerous to execute an arbitrary string, but that works if it is a one-time script.)